# Trying to compile simple project that uses TRI DDS using cygwin gcc

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to take the TRI DDS example code. It is all setup to build with MSVS2012 and comes with MSVS2012 proj/solution files.

However I want to try to build this using Cygwin and g++/gcc. I have got so far and then hit issues.

My cpp/h files are taken from their example - the user code is basic c++ but the generated files / RTI DDS files I think are causing an issue.

The basic source files are:

```
Hello.cpp
HelloPublisher.cpp/h
HelloSubscriber.cpp/h
HelloWorld.idl
```

RTI-DDS generator uses `HelloWorld.idl` to generate further files (.cxx/h files). I am not expecting to change any of the RTI-DDS files and the code within the 4 source files are fairly vanilla, so I can compile them if I hack out all the calls to RTI-DDS.

The area I want to focus on is the makefile / environment. Here are the pertinent parts of my makefile (**note** the linker parts are not complete because I have not got that far yet - the compile still fails):

**note** `NDDSHOME = c:\Program Files\rti_connext_dds-5.3.0` as an env var.

```
# Setup minimal "un-polluted" paths to try to avoid any conflicts
makePaths=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$(NDDSHOME)/bin
export PATH := $(makePaths)

#Include Paths
INCLUDES = -I. -I"$(NDDSHOME)/include" -I"$(NDDSHOME)/include/ndds" -I"$(NDDSHOME)/include/ndds/hpp"

#Compiler / options:
DEFINES = -DRTI_WIN32 -DRTI_STATIC -DWIN32 -D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -lWS2_32
EXEC = run

# C++ files
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES.cpp=.o)

# Main Target
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
#    Don't do linking yet - compile not working!

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $< -o $@ -c $(DEFINES) $(CC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
```

I know the INCLUDES paths are working because I get different errors when they are not (can't find...)

But the error I get at the moment is:

```
/usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:1004:68: error: conflicting declaration of c function 'int gethostname(char*, int)'
      :
      :
/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:268:6 note: previous declration 'int gethostname(char *, size_t)'
```

**note** I have to copy this by hand from my other PC... so I have abbreviated the complete message.

I thought I was close to solving this by looking at other questions with similar errors, but I can't quite make the connection to fix this. I have tried adding other defines to specify the windows version, but that did not fix it. I know there is a linker option that we need to use for things like mingw that is what the `-lws2_32` flag is set for - but I have not got to the linker stage yet :(

I guess either the unistd.h or the winsock2.h should not really both be included, but I can't quite figure out what define (or other) I need to add...

Any ideas?

Comment: Cygwin is an environment that emulates POSIX. Using it you should either use POSIX only, or Windows only, when building. Do not mix. If you want to use GCC and other POSIX-like tools, but otherwise not emulate POSIX and use Windows only building, then consider MinGW and MSYS instead of Cygwin.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok - that makes sense, I'll try to get mingw... I am guessing its not really possible to use Cygwin since the library I have is a windows install... : (